# Email 'mapping' to localhost for local email solution for valid email address

Tags: email, email-server

I'm on Windows using XAMPP and have Mercury Mail set up working fine for local mail. To get this working I need to use addresses such as, user@localhost

But it's a pain when I use email address validation in my scripts that require a properly formed email address, ie, with a domain extension like .com, .net, .co.uk etc on the end.

If I set up an address like user@local.dev, or even user@example.com, is there a place (ini, conf, hosts file or similar) where I can get this to 'map' to user@localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercury "Configuration" menu option then "Alias..."

Comment: Not a problem...

Comment: I am running into the same problem using Drupal 7 amd XAMPP. I added the aliases and domains for localhost and localhost.com but I am still getting a Temporary error 249 (temporary MX resolution error). Where are MX records kept in XAMPP?

Comment: It does not appear that XAMPP includes any actual email nor DNS servers. If your XAMPP configuration does include an email server (like the OP), then which email server is it? It will vary based upon the email server.